# Android List View Button make a call

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to put a button on my listView item and make a call... but so far, I couldn't figure out how to assign that data to that button action and here is my code... The list item itself is not clickable, only the button is. I use an adapter to get the data from the array

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    //Get the current location object
    info lm = (info) getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView = dInflater.inflate(R.layout.dealbranch_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        holder.call = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.call);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(lm.getName());


    holder.call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent call = new Intent (Itent.ACTION_CALL);

            ///  No clue.. >,<  ///  /// lm.getPhone() should get the phone# for this row.
            /// this action does not work   /////

        startActivity(call);
    }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Would be great if someone could show me the way. Thanks.

Comment: pass the phone number in constructor of that adapter you made and call that number.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more? much appreciated =)

Comment: see @azgolfer's answer, exactly what i would advice you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know how you define the class 'info' so here's my guess:

first, change the line:

```
info lm = (info) getItem(position);
```

to

```
final info lm = (info) getItem(position);
```

then here's how to invoke ACTION_DIAL with phone number:

```
holder.call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent call = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + lm.getPhone()));

        ///  No clue.. >,<  ///  /// lm.getPhone() should get the phone# for this row.
        /// this action does not work   /////

    startActivity(call);
}
```

This is assuming the lm.getPhone() method returns a phone number in string.

Comment: thanks, it works... only now that startActivity is undefined on new onClickListener and cannot start =(

Comment: Well, you can always try context.startActivity(xxxx); Where context is the activity you passed into your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: not work =(  System.out.println(lm.getPhone()); i got the phone number correct. using the above code, i got NullPointerExeception;  And so is just using "tel:00000000"

Comment: Where did you put System.out.println(lm.getPhone())? It doesn't make sense if it shows a phone number string, but becomes null pointer inside 'onClick'.

Comment: i put it inside onClick, so when i click i see the phone# in the log. the nullPointer might come from the context.startActivity?

Comment: Could you provide your final usage of getContext()?