# Using ACTION_CALL on list view

Tags: android

can anyone tel me whats wrong with this code? please

i can see "Log" correctly but ACTION_CAL dose not work...

```
    final int pos = position;

    ImageView ImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.call);

    ImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("name :: ", feedItems.get(pos).getName());

            String message = feedItems.get(pos).getName();
            String number = "tel:" + message.toString().trim();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }

        private void startActivity(Intent callIntent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android List View Button make a call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480736/android-list-view-button-make-a-call)

Answer (score 0):

What is this

```
private void startActivity(Intent callIntent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

Please remove it and use `context.startActivity(Intent intent);`

If your adapter is in activity or in fragment just call `startActivity(callIntent)`

If is a complete seprate class and pass context in constructor from your activity or fragment.

Like

```
   private Context mContext;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
      mContext = context;
   }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.v("name :: ", feedItems.get(pos).getName());

        String message = feedItems.get(pos).getName();
        String number = "tel:" + message.toString().trim();
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
        mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

add permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: its crash..i10-13 14:51:49.955: E/AndroidRuntime(21954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 14:51:49.955: E/AndroidRuntime(21954): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 14:51:49.955: E/AndroidRuntime(21954):  at com.krs.feed.adapter.FeedListAdapter$2.onClick(FeedListAdapter.java:111)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are in an adapter, where u can't call startActivity.
If you use a ListAdapter or others you can simply replace this line:
`startActivity(callIntent);`
withi this:
`getContext().startActivity(callIntent);`

Comment: yes you are right i'm using ListAdapter... but unfortunately your code dose not work ether...

Comment: same error. E/AndroidRuntime(21954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-13 14:51:49.955: E/AndroidRuntime(21954): java.lang.NullPointerException 10-13 14:51:49.955: E/AndroidRuntime(21954): at com.krs.feed.adapter.FeedListAdapter$2.onClick(FeedListAdapter.java:111)

Comment: @Riz can you specify which line is the 111 of this code?

Comment: mContext.startActivity(callIntent);